# Magento 2 Add to cart button hide when click

Tags: magento2, addtocart, add

I want the button to be removed after clicking on add to cart and show positive negative instead

And when we click on the negative and the number becomes zero or click on delete , the button will be appear again

```
Same as the photo
```

[image]